# BackgroundWorker ReportProgress event queue

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker that monitors a folder for files in 1sec interval. If it finds file(s) then it raises the ReportProgress(0, fileName) for every found file.

On the main thread I subscribe to that event and handle each file.

This is:  one found file = one raised event = one handled file

My question is about queuing events if the main thread is slow.
For example the 'file watcher' can find and raise 1000 events per second but on the main thread handling each file takes 1 sec. So events are queued.

Is there any limit for that kind of queuing in .NET ?

Thanks,
Bartek

Comment: You could use the [`FileSystemWatcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) instead of the background worker?

Comment: ``FileSystemWatcher`` is unreliable when frequent/major changes occur. Changing it's internal buffer may help, but there is a hard limit on it too.

Answer (score 1):

No the main thread will *eventually* process all the files. However, if you have some sort of GUI I would recommend you do the processing on a separate thread.

Comment: This is a windows service so this should be fine. I just wanted to know if anything would not be missed but as you say this looks ok. Thanks

Comment: @bodziec all your events should get handled unless of course an exception happens during the processing of one. However, there are a couple of ways you can handle that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker` internally uses `SynchronizationContext` to `Post` asynchronous messages. If it was GUI thread starting the BW, it'd use a specialized WinForms `SynchronizationContext` and report progress to that main thread using message loop.

In your case, it's a windows service thread and as such has no `SynchronizationContext`. What happens is the default `SynchronizationContext` is instantiated and used. The behavior is then completely different and a new `ThreadPool` is used for asynchronous messages. As a result, your file processing will take place in separate threads started by that internal `ThreadPool`, as opposed to main thread as it is in WinForms.

While `ThreadPool` should correctly handle large queues (could not immediately find any hard limits on ThreadPool queue size - anyone know?), do know that you can not assume deterministic sequential file processing in this pattern.

Comment: As far as I am aware there are no hard limits on a ThreadPool queue. The only restriction would be the machine having enough resources to process the load.